# Fedora 24 - Ruby on Rails installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedora

I tried install rails on my fresh Fedora 24 instalation . I followed this tutorial https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/ror-installation.html .

But I got this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160918-22847-14vriyi.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate    an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
from /usr/share/ruby/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:3:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nio4r-1.2.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out
```

I googled solution but I wasn't successful. Can you please give me advice? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you check the mkmf.log file?  Can you post what it contains?  As the error says, the file is in `/usr/local/lib64/gems/ruby/nio4r-1.2.1/mkmf.log`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed "development tools", per the error message in your logs?

> The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>
> You have to install development tools first.

From [the linked Fedora ROR installation guide](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/ror-installation.html):

```
sudo dnf group install "C Development Tools and Libraries"
```

Comment: Yes I did, as I mentioned I followed this tutorial https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/ror-installation.html and it is a first step.

Comment: Based on that error message, it looks like those packages either haven't been installed or aren't available to your Ruby process. I don't use Fedora/Yum, but it looks like you can verify that they've been installed using: `yum groupinfo "C Development Tools and Libraries"`.